# Simple question about positioning class-created display objects in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

Take this class:

```
    package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class test extends MovieClip {

        public function test(parentMC) {
            var s=new MovieClip()
            s.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000,1)
            s.graphics.drawCircle(200,200,100)
            parentMC.addChild(s)
        }

    }

}
```

Why does the following code not move the created circle and how can I make it do so?

```
var s=new test(stage)
s.x=500
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
package  

{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Test extends Sprite   
    {

        public function Test() 
        {
            graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000,1);
            graphics.drawCircle(200,200,100);
            graphcis.endFill();

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

and implement it like this:

```
var test:Test = new Test();
test.x = 500;
addChild(test);
```

The problem was that you weren't adding the Test's class's local display object (in the `Test` class's constructor) to the `Test` display object container, you were adding it to the `parentMC` display object container.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you are not returning "s" from your function.

```
public function test(parentMC) {
            var s=new MovieClip()
            s.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000,1)
            s.graphics.drawCircle(200,200,100)
            parentMC.addChild(s)
            return s; // THIS IS MISSING
        }
```

Comment: The `test()` method is the constructor for the `test` class, you can't specify a return type for the constructor.

Comment: I haven't specified a return type for the constructor.  
That would look like this. 
public function test(parentMC):MoiveClip 
you can return a value from your constructor function, which is what I have done here.